# Setting mmenu to trigger on a tablet (@768px)

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using the mmenu plugin with Bootstrap 3 and would like the menu to collapse at 768px (currently collapses at 767px).

Can this be set in mmenu or should this be set in Bootstrap?

Essentially, I want the mobile version of the menu to show up on the tablet viewport.

Comment: Are you building bootstrap from less?

Comment: Yes, I am using less.

Comment: You can set `@grid-float-breakpoint: @screen-sm-min + 1` variable in less and then build again and your done.

Comment: And that will cause the mmenu to trigger at 768px?

Comment: Yes it will it is the variable that bootstrap use internally to calculate the navbar collapse point.